# Loading website on port 1433 without using ":1433"

Tags: port, apache2, watchguard, firebox

Boss wants me to set up a website so that by typing "https://www.example.com" (no :1433) in the address bar of a web browser, the request will go through port 1433 on a Watchguard Firebox to an apache web server with domain-ssl.conf containing

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
     ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example.com/requests.log combined
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example/apache.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example/apache.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example/apache.ca-bundle​
</VirtualHost>
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to achieve this is to put something in between which is listening on Port 443, such as a load balancer, proxy etc.

Other than that, without a specific port, any conventional web browser is going to request either Port 80 or Port 443 by default.